# Transform a (very small) crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box).</sub>

---

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/ywzfpyyv) <sub>(no answer check)</sub>

The only way to fill this grid is to make it ____.

**Across**
1. Republican of sound mind gets behind Mr Lincoln? That's not normal at all!
4. Frank and I got accepted into Oxygen Gas, a London-based band (*2 wds.*)
5. Making livable fort, rearming rebels
7. Negligible importance of Prohibition agent Eliot's nickname after three extramarital affairs, perhaps?

**Down**
1. Raider's beer-drunk, kidnapping key representatives of Scottish breed (*2 wds.*)
2. In administration, educators restricted
3. Heroic expedition destroyed alien's bones? That is dubious quality!
6. Circulating gold regularly found during search for minerals

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only way to fill this grid is to make it:

> **Fourier** - i.e. more "four"y, because we have to put four letters in each box to make sense of the crossword.
>
>  Also noting the hint in the title that a [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) converts between time- and frequency- domains.

The completed grid:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

The clues:

> Across
>  1. Republican of sound mind gets behind Mr Lincoln? **That's not normal at all!**
>  **ABERRATIONAL** - ABE + R + RATIONAL
>
>  4. Frank and I got accepted into Oxygen Gas, **a London-based band** (2 wds.)
>  **ONE DIRECTION** DIRECT + I in O + NEON
>
>  5. **Making livable** fort, rearming rebels
>  **TERRAFORMING** - (FORTREARMING)*
>
>  7. **Negligible importance** of Prohibition agent Eliot's nickname after three extramarital affairs, perhaps?
>  **TRIFLINGNESS** - TRI-FLING + NESS
>
>  Down
>  1. Raider's beer-drunk, kidnapping key **representatives of Scottish breed** (2 wds.)
>  **ABERDEEN TERRIERS** - ENTER in (RAIDERSBEER)*
>
>  2. In administration, educators **restricted**
>  **RATIONED** - (administ)RATION ED(ucators)
>
>  3. Heroic expedition destroyed alien's bones? That is **dubious quality**!
>  **QUESTIONABLENESS** - QUEST + (ALIENSBONES)*
>
>  6. **Circulating** gold regularly found during search for minerals
>  **MINGLING** - G_L_ in MINING

Finally:

> Reading the background letter+numeral as a hint the take the nth letter from that square and order A-G gives us:
>
> ```
>  A(ii)  aFor
>  B(i)   Oned
>  C(ii)  qUes
>  D(i)   Rati
>  E(i)   Iers
>  F(ii)  nEss
>  G(iii) teRr
> ```

Comment: You're missing a letter in the explanation to 4A - good solve!

Comment: @samm82 Thanks. Looks like GentlePurpleRain has already corrected it.